# Tensorflow bias and weight variable

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have created a deep convolutional neural network for pixel-wise classification. My images for training are of size 32x32x7, therfore the number 7168 is used a lot. Below you can see my final result of my model being reshaped and modified by a weight and bias. I am a little confused about this weight and bias. **Will the weight and bias automatically be adjusted during training of the model?** I never assign a value for these variables, so I am assuming the train_step will modify them according to the cross entropy score. Is this correct?

```
final = tf.add(add1,add2)
final = tf.reshape(final, [-1, 7168])

W_final = weight_variable([7168,7168,3])
b_final = bias_variable([7168,3])
final_conv = tf.tensordot(final, W_final, axes=[[1], [1]]) + b_final

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=y_,  logits=final_conv))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-5, epsilon = .1).minimize(cross_entropy)
```

Comment: What are `weight_variable` and `bias_variable`, are those your functions or classes or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens to the variables that you create in a model depends on what you do with them. The typical use case for TensorFlow, as you point out, is to have them automatically adjusted ("trained") according to some loss score, in your case the cross-entropy. You have the tensor `cross_entropy` which computes the loss, and `train_step`, an optimization operation that updates the trainable variables in the model (by default, the variables you create are trainable unless `trainable=False` is specified) according to some rule depending on the value of `cross_entropy`. What you need in addition to that is:

- A [`tf.global_variables_initializer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/global_variables_initializer) operation.
- A new [session](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session).
- Run the variable initializer operation in the session. This will give initial values to your variables. Note that the nature of this initial values will depend on the initializers that you chose when you created the variables (zeros, random normal, etc.).
- Run `train_step` with your training data until `cross_entropy` has a "good enough" value. Every time you do this the values of the variables will change a little to fit the model to the data.

So actually everything that happens with the variables is more or less explicit. And you can choose to do whatever else with them, you can have some non-trainable variables, for example, you can add regularizers, etc.